# AlarmManager executes my PendingIntent immediately instead of waiting for sertain time

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, alarmmanager, receiver

I am trying to implement an alarm, and therefore my app has 2 activities: main one (where the user sets an alarm) and the 'ringing' one which is displayed when the alarm is actually triggered. Here is how I send an intent for AlarmManager to call the 'ringing' window:

```
public void scheduleAlarm(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, WakeUp.class);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    PendingIntent wakeUp = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 123, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calculateMillis(), wakeUp); // setExact is pretty much made for setting alarms anyway
}

private long calculateMillis() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    return cal.getTimeInMillis() - Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
}
```

In my manifest I have the following:

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".WakeUpWithMath"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".WakeUp"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_wake_up"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

I have tested it multiple times and with different values for the calculateMillis (even mocked to return 30000) yet the result is always the same: right after calling `alarmManager.setExact`it displayes the 'ringing' activity and does not wait for the time to pass at first.

What have I missed? Is the manifest configured wrong? do I need to use a `<receiver>` tag? if so, how should I configure it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setExact` uses absolute time, not relative time. Use the time returned by `cal.getTimeInMillis()` without subtracting current time.

Comment: sadly, it now doesn't launch at all, any idea what else could be wrong?

Comment: @niralittle You probably set the time too much in the future. `Calendar` uses local time if no different timezone is set.

Comment: basically, if I got it right, it used to launch it immediately because the time was less than the present time and such behavior is expected, but now.. maybe locale or...anything specific I should look into?

Comment: I only set it 1 minute in future.  What value is the `calculateMillis` value passed by me compared to by the system?

Comment: You can check the difference from `System.currentTimeMillis()` to see how many milliseconds in future it will trigger